# In what circumstances the AI will calculate the user insights?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have created the SharePoint WebPart with fetching the user insights data from Microsoft Graph API and display.

I tested it using Graph Explorer
with this  :

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/insights/used&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

[Or click this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/insights/used&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com)

In some users, it gives me a result perfectly, In some users, it gives me an empty value.

**(Those users are doing the same thing)**

So, in what circumstances the AI will calculate the user insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week for my research and experiment with it, it seems that the insights/used are only calculate when the user creates or modifies the file(s).

Unlike mentioned in the document

[image]
Maybe because it is currently in the beta and is subject to change, hopefully, it will be able to use soon enough.